# Finding the center of the $1992^\text{nd}$ circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, analytic-geometry, circles

Consider the triangle whose vertices are $(0,0),(0,3),$ and $(4,0)$. Let $\Gamma_{1}$ be the greatest circle that can be drawn inside the triangle. For $n>1$, let $\Gamma_{n}$ be the greatest circle that can be drawn inside the triangle and does not overlap the $(n-1)$ greater circles, and is not in the region bounded by $\Gamma_{1}$ and the coordinate axes. Which of the following points is closest to the center of $\Gamma_{1992}?$

$\text{(A)}\space(0,1)\space \space \space \space \space\text{(B)}\space(0,3)\space \space \space \space \space\text{(C)}\space(1,0)\space \space \space \space \space\text{(D)}\space(\frac{8}{5},\frac{9}{5})\space \space \space \space \space\text{(E)}\space(4,0)$

---

This problem appeared in one of the math competitions in my city. The average time to solve this problem is $15$ minutes.

---

I tried to find a pattern between $n$ and the given points. (of course $n \ne 1$ because it is equidistance from $\text{(A),(C)}$, and $\text{(D)}$). For $n=2$, the correct option is $\text{(E)}$. For $n = 3$, the correct option is $\text{(B)}$. Then for $n \ge 4$ is is tedious!

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

I used Mathematica to construct iteratively 2723 circles (with a cutoff of $r=1/700$) and then reordered the list to find n° 1992. It turns out that circles n° 1991 and 1992 have the same radius ($0.00181207$) and their centers are located at:
$$
C_{1991}=(2.45007, 1.05146);
\quad
C_{1992}=(2.12919, 0.0887912).
$$
Hence $C_{1991}$ is nearer to point $D$, while $C_{1992}$ is nearer to point $C$ and no definite answer can be given, unless some other criteria are adopted for ordering circles.

Below is a picture of the result, but the above circles are too small to be seen at this scale.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Is there any evidence of a pattern in the ordered list of circles? Clearly the question doesn't expect us to construct all the circles.

Comment: @nickgard I haven't detected any pattern, but there is a symmetry about both angle bisectors, leading to pairs of circles with the same radius: $\Gamma_{1991}$ and $\Gamma_{1992}$ are symmetric about the bisector of $\angle CED$. I suspect the text of the question hasn't been reported correctly.

Comment: Very nice! The observation about symmetry is critical. It follows that unless the center of $\Gamma_\ell$ is not on one of the bisectors, it will have a mirror pair.

Comment: +1 In any event, I figured out an analytic closed-form of the centers and radii. $\Gamma_{1991}$, $\Gamma_{1992}$ are centered at $\left(\frac{39006\,\sqrt{10}-22711}{41075},\frac{87277-13942\,\sqrt{10}}{41075}\right)$ and 
$\left(\frac{7914\,\sqrt{10}-7535}{8215},\frac{49\,\left(173- 50\sqrt{10}\right) }{8215}\right)$ respectively. Their common radii is $\frac{173- 50\sqrt{10}}{8215}$.

Comment: @achillehui Wonderful result. I gave up using exact computing in Mathematica because it was too time-consuming, but I did very little to optimise the results. Glad you can confirm my result. It remains to understand what was the real meaning of this problem.